# Apex tests and Run test option

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have a question about running apex tests and why i can't see that "Run Test" under IsTest annotation
just like on the first screenshot[image]

What i see is something like this
[image]

Comment: Similar question with alternative solutions:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/414085/108203

Answer (score 1):

First update your extension to latest version. As per [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/apex/testing/)

> If you don’t see this icon, make sure that the project contains an sfdx-project.json file in its root directory.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure Apex Language Server is running, you can check it on Output tab (`CTRL + SHIFT + U`).
If it is not running, most likely you don't have a valid Java runtime installed. It will work only with Java8 or Java11.
In this case:

- from Extension tab check for updates.
- close VS Code.
- download and install [AdoptOpenJDK 11](https://adoptopenjdk.net/).
- be sure to set JAVA_HOME variable.
- restart VS Code.

You may find useful enable `Retrieve-test-code-coverage` option.